# Do I need any jQuery plugin to work with PushState in the newest browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to play with `history.pushState()` in the latest Firefox and Chrome. It looks simple to use and in my current project I don't want to be bothered by supporting legacy browsers because it's a personal project where I can just experiment. So I wonder if there any caveats or nuances in working with it for which I would need some plugins that will make the life easier?

Comment: I prefer https://github.com/balupton/History.js/, which works seamlessly on all versions of IE, whilst using `pushState` on Chrome etc. It is not necessarily a plugin for jQuery but you can easily implement it with jQuery.

Comment: @pimvdb please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744487/statechange-is-firing-whenever-i-do-a-push-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the behavior of `pushState()` is inconsistent across browsers. Checkout Remy Sharp's [pushState demo](http://html5demos.com/history). [History.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history-js) seems to be a solid lib for this which also has graceful degradation.

Comment: please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744487/statechange-is-firing-whenever-i-do-a-push-state