# Statechange is firing whenever i do a push-state

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, history.js

I am using history.js to handle back button. In history.js statechange is firing whenever i do a pushstate. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [discussion on github](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/96), it's expected behaviour of history.js

This [pull request](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/pull/137) claims to have modified history.js to be more inline  with W3C Specs.

Comment: Million thanks. I personally feel history.js solution is better.

Answer (score 12):

Wanted to add, yes this is the expected behaviour of History.js.
At the same time there are [more discussions](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/47) that critize this behaviour as it is not the W3C standard and does create some confusion.

In short, to answer your question: In the History.js `pushState()` function is a call to statechange at the end.

**Upside** of this solution is that you can just change (push) your new state and let the onstatechange()-function handle the transition. **Downside** is that you are not able to handle exceptions/or have to write them into the onstatechange event-handler.

I personally prefer the W3C way of handling this, as you can distinguish between back/forward button and pushState. The History.js maintainers are working on an internal flag solution, that enables you to change this behaviour:

> Notice how the above calls [pushstate-calls] trigger statechange events, if for some
>   reason you do not want this to happen then inside your statechange
>   handler you can use the following:

```
if ( History.getState().internal ) { return; }
```

*This feature is currently in development and can only be used with the 'dev' version of History.js! Hope this will help some other people in the future :)

Answer (score 9):

After trying to accomplish this for a day now, I finally found the solution here: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/47#issuecomment-25750285

The code is pretty damn simple, the following is quoted from the link:

When you push your state

```
History.pushState({
    _index: History.getCurrentIndex(),
    someData: ...
}, someTitle, someUrl);
```

and then in the event binding

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
    var currentIndex = History.getCurrentIndex();
    var internal = (History.getState().data._index == (currentIndex - 1));
    if (!internal) {
        // your action
    }
});
```